# In JSP I have changed and HREF is not coming

Tags: jsp, aem

I am very new to JSP and have written below JSP for my Dialog , but href is not coming in page , as shown below.

```
<%@include file="/apps/myproject/global.jsp"%> 
Industry Level1 Updates

<% String title=properties.get("linkLabel",""); %>

<c:set var="industriesPlaceholder" value="- Click to add Industries navigation -"/> <slingx:property var="industriesTitle" name="title" resourcePath="./industriesLinks"/>

<c:out value="${empty industriesTitle && isEditMode ? industriesPlaceholder : ''}" escapeXml="${escapeXml}" />

<c:set var="industriesLinksNode" value="${tef:getRelativeResource(resource, 'industriesLinks')}" />

${industriesTitle}
        <slingx:property var="industrylabel" name="label" resourcePath="${industriesResource.path}" />
        <slingx:property var="industryDestination" name="destination" resourcePath="${industriesResource.path}" />
        <div class="top-nav-auth-item-wrapper">
            <li><a href="<tef:link path="${empty industryDestination ? # : industryDestination}"/>">
                <span>${industrylabel}</span>
            </a></li>
        </div>

</c:if>
```

My dialog is below:

[image: Dialog Image]

Comment: what AEM version are you working with? Using jsp is not the way to go any more in AEM - for at least 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like code you posted is way to old implementation and its bit messed up and not so clear. if you put clearly then it will be helpful to run and see the output. however, putting example you can try

```
<c:url value="${empty industryDestination ? # : industryDestination}" var="myURL"></c:url>
<a href="${myURL}">
    <span>${industrylabel}</span>
</a>
```

also not very clear what "<tef:link" is in below anchor href?, seems like a wrong tag & expression?

```
<a href="<tef:link path="${empty industryDestination ? # : industryDestination}"/>">
```

but if it to generating link then first example may help and also <c:set> <c:out> can help too, but I am not too sure of intent behind it.

On the other hand HTL will be good and easy option to do if you converting entire script to sightly

```
<sly data-sly-test.result="${!industryDestination ? '#' : industryDestination}"></sly>
<a href="${result}">
    <span>${industrylabel}</span>
</a>
```